# How to post photo/image to facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to post an image to friend's facebook wall through graph api?If anybody suceed please send the web reuest or graph url.Here is my graph url.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Pageid/feed?access_token=application_access_token&method=post&picture=http://www.Google.es/images/srpr/nav_logo39.png&message=logo
```

It is working fine ,image get posted on the page.But when I am trying to give  url of image (that stored on my desktop)logic get fails.Here is it's url.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Pageid/feed?access_token=application_access_token&method=post&picture=D:/foldername/Cimage.jpg&message=Waterfall.
```

I can't directly put all image that user upload to my server and then post to facebook.I wanted user to directly post an image to facebook wall not through my server (I don't want any  image that hosted somewhere I wanted to use the image that get stored on harddisk.)

Comment: I searched on net requarding to this,I found that need to create album first then add image to the album.then use that image url for posting.when image get posted in album it's link is
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=s … ileid.When I am use this link ,throws an error that id already specified.Am I going in right direction?Let me know ,if anyone succeed.

Comment: If I remove that id(profile id) from link(http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=someno&l=number) then it throws an error saying that "message": "(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream:.